# Declaring Large Object Array in PHP as javascript Arguments

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, object

I need to pass a PHP array to a javascript function where the array has the form

```
var Waypoints = [{"Geometry":{"Latitude":52.34,"Longitude":55.35}},{"Geometry":{"Latitude":55.34,"Longitude":56.35}}]
```

Here is a code snippet:

```
class Geometry
{
  public $Latitude;
  public $Longitude;
}
class WayPoint
{
  public $Geometry;
}
$Geometry = new Geometry();

$wp = new WayPoint();
$wp->Geometry->Latitude = 52.34;
$wp->Geometry->Longitude = 55.35;

$wp2 = new WayPoint();
$wp2->Geometry->Latitude = 55.34;
$wp2->Geometry->Longitude = 56.35;

$php_data = [$wp,$wp2 ];
echo json_encode($php_data);
```

which produces this:

```
[{"Geometry":{"Latitude":52.34,"Longitude":55.35}},{"Geometry":{"Latitude":55.34,"Longitude":56.35}}]
```

This is the correct array structure, however I am asking two questions:

1. Is this the best way of declaring the object classes with regarding to filling the array with a very large number of co-ordinates, and
2. Why is PHP giving a warning for the code on lines, 13 and 16 regarding empty values, i.e.

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in for
>   $wp->Geometry->Latitude = 52.34; and $wp2->Geometry->Latitude = 55.34;

From what I can discern from the documentation, this is the correct way of declaring an object, and why is it just the first variable is being flagged?

Comment: The warning is simply because your classes don't have any constructors. There's nothing to initialize so instead it creates a default object.

Comment: @icecub Nope, its because this line `$wp->Geometry->Latitude =..` .The `Geometry` property of the `$wp` object is null, but the code attempts to set a property on it.

Comment: @Steve Ah. I'm in the process of studying C# (not quite there yet) and I remembered something about the need of a constructor on normal classes. Could be wrong though. Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you dont assign the `Geometry` property of the `Waypoint` objects.

It still works because php will create a default object (called a `stdClass`) when you assign a property to a non existent variable.

There is a much simpler solution - json_encode will take an asociative array as input:

```
echo json_encode(
    [
        [
            'Geometry'=>
                [
                    'Latitude'  =>  52.34,
                    'Longtitude'=>  55.35,
                ]
        ],
        [
            'Geometry'=>
                [
                    'Latitude'  =>  52.65,
                    'Longtitude'=>  56.35,
                ]
        ],
    ]
);
```

Obviously you can build this array in a loop.

If you do want to use named classes, for other reasons, then the correct code would be:

```
class Geometry
{
  public $Latitude;
  public $Longitude;
}
class WayPoint
{
  public $Geometry;
}

$data=[];


$wp = new WayPoint();
$gm = new Geometry();
$gm->Latitude = 52.34;
$gm->Longitude = 55.35;

$wp->Geometry = $gm;

$data[]=$wp;


echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thanks Steve.  Yes, I would prefer to remain with named classes from the perspective of looping structure etc, but the other way of approaching of using json_encode directly is helpful.

Comment: you could also give `WayPoint` a constructor that initializes `$this->Geometry`.

Answer (score 0):

Taking both Steve's comments and Barmar's comments (regarding the use of a constructor) I was able to simplify the implementation a little more and making neater.   I hope this helps someone looking to do the same thing.

```
class Geometry
{
   public $Latitude;
   public $Longitude;
}
class WayPoint
{
   public function __construct($Lat, $Long)
   {
       $geometry = new Geometry();
       $geometry->Latitude = $Lat;
       $geometry->Longitude = $Long;
       $this->Geometry = $geometry;
   }
}

$wp = new WayPoint(52.34,68.89);
$wp2 = new WayPoint(55.45,67.89);

$php_data = [$wp,$wp2 ];
echo json_encode($php_data);
```